# CasperJS 1.0.4 - error in this.getElementsInfo()

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I am new to casperJS. I have installed casperJS 1.0.4 and phantomJS 1.8.2 on windows 8.

My objective is to scrape some data from net. i want to open this [webpage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_towns_in_Vermont) and fetch the list of towns in vermont. I replicated the code given by [Victor W Yee](http://www.victorwyee.com/js/webscraping-with-casperjs-phantomjs/). When i run the code, it opens the desired page, i take a snapshot of it as verification but when i try and fetch data from the table I get an error on this line:

```
var town_names_info = this.getElementsInfo(town_selector);
```

*Error says:*

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function(evaluating'this.getElementsInfo(town_selector)')
F:/Trial Codes/intro to casper_JS/Vermont/vermont.js:21
F:/Trial Codes/intro to casper_JS/Vermont:1335 in runStep
F:/Trial Codes/intro to casper_JS/Vermont:332 in checkStep
```

Any suggestions ??

My whole code is:

```
var utils = require('utils');
var casper = require('casper').create({
verbose: false,
logLevel: 'debug'
});

var url = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_towns_in_Vermont';
var town_selector;

casper.start(url, function() {
this.capture("result1.png");
this.echo("* "+this.getTitle()+" *");
});

casper.then(function() {
// Get info on all elements matching this CSS selector
town_selector = 'table[id="sortable wikitable"] tbody tr td:nth-of-type(2)';

var town_names_info = this.getElementsInfo(town_selector); // an array of object literals

// Pull out the town name text and push into the town_names array
var town_names = [];
for (var i = 0; i < town_names_info.length; i++) 
{
town_names.push(town_names_info[i].text);
}

// Dump the town_names array to screen
utils.dump(town_names);

});

casper.run(function() {
this.exit();    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[`getElementsInfo()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#getelementsinfo) was added in CasperJS version 1.1 (note the green note in the page). You can use 1.1.0-beta3 because this "beta" version is actually stable. While you're at it updating, you should use a more up-to-date version of PhantomJS such as 1.9.7 or 1.9.8 (has some problems with CasperJS).